# Error in MySQL when running a command

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error when I run a MySQL command:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''champions' WHERE 'id' = $'id'' at line 1

How to solve this error? What does it mean?

Comment: What's your SQL query?

Comment: Where is your query then?

Comment: Share your SQL query!

Comment: Who on earth would up vote this?

Comment: @HoboSapiens Probably someone really smart and handsome

Comment: From the StackOverflow Help Center: [**What should I do when someone answers my question?** http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Three things.

1. MySQL doesn't like the dangling `$` in the query. so change `$'id'` to `'$id'`
2. `'id'` is the literal string `'id'`, not the value of the column `id`, so get rid of the single quotes
3. Assuming `champions` is a table, you need to get rid of the single quotes from around that as well

Comment: The error is likely *before* the `$'id`. Likely, an unbalanced (missing or extra) single quote. Also looks like OP may be enclosing identifiers in single quotes rather than backticks; but it's perfectly valid to compare a string literal to another string literal... `WHERE 'foo' = 'bar'`, but that will never be true, because the string literal `foo` will never equal the string `bar`. But you are right, once the earlier syntax problem is fixed, MySQL is going to balk at the `$` character.

Comment: can only reflect on what is present in the question. it's entirely likely that the dangling quote near champions and id is the root cause, and fixing all of the above will fix the query

Comment: I think the problem is either a missing single quote before `champion'`, or if there is a single quote there (not shown) it's being interpreted as the *end* a prior string literal. Impossible to tell how to fix the statement without seeing the actual statement being submitted to the database, but all of your observations are spot on (as usual.)

Answer (score 1):

How to fix it?  Correct the statement so that it's valid SQL syntax.

What does the error mean?  The error means that MySQL thinks that the statement it received is invalid SQL.

Usually, the error indicates the point in the statement at which MySQL thinks the statement went from being valid to being invalid. In this case, the error is showing:

```
    champions' WHERE 'id' = $'id
```

When MySQL got to that part, it was like *what the plastic?* and *I can't do anything with this*...

I think the biggest issue here is that you may be enclosing column names in single quotes. Don't do that.

Single quotes go around string literals (*values*); if an identifier needs to be escaped, enclose it in backticks.

```
... FROM t WHERE t.`lastname` = 'Smith'
```

From the portion of the statement shown, it looks like you might mean for `id` to be a column name, not a string literal. But the problem MySQL is reporting is earlier in the statement than that.

Likely, it thought a single quote immediately preceding **`champions`** marked the end of a string literal. (Or, there was supposed to be a single quote before `champions'` but it's missing. It's impossible to tell what the actual problem is without seeing the SQL statement that's being submitted. We're just guessing.

To debug this, `echo` or `vardump` the SQL text *before* you submit it to the database, e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE fee = 'fo'";
echo "SQL=" . $sql ;  // for debugging
$db->query($sql);
```

(The `$'id` in the error makes me believe you are dynamically creating a string containing the SQL statement in PHP, intending to have PHP evaluate a variable $id and supply the value in the SQL text.

Hopefully, `$id` doesn't contain something like **`0' OR '1'='1'`**.

To summarize:

- for debugging, echo out the actual string containing the SQL you are submitting to the database
- use **backticks** not single quotes around identifiers (table names, colum names)
- use **single quotes** around string literals
- properly **escape** values incorporated into SQL text (`real_escape_string`)
- a single quote within a string literal has to be escaped, use **two single quotes** to represent a single quote, e.g.  `'O''Reilly'` ->  `O'Reilly`

For example, if you do this:

```
SELECT foo FROM tab WHERE `name` = 'O'Reilly'
```

MySQL is going to balk at `Reilly`. What it sees as valid is **`name = 'O'`** (column equal to a string literal containing a single character). MySQL then throws a syntax error starting at `Reilly`.

This looks like what's happening in your query, with `champion'`.  The actual problem is probably a missing, or unbalanced single quote, and that could be a lot earlier in the statement.

Answer (score -2):

It means you have an error in your query. You probably have an apostrophe that you don't need in $'id. It should be $id. If this doesn't resolve you problem, provide more details, the entire query.